# How to use Admob API on c# via Service Account?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, admob, google-api-dotnet-client

I'd like to use Admob API on a server-to-server app made with .net via Service Account to avoid manual login to require the token. After creating the certification, I wrote this dependency:

```
public AdMobService RegisterAdMobService(IServiceFactory factory)
        {
            var settings = factory.GetInstance<IOptions<SettingsModel>>().Value.AdMob;
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(settings.CertificateFileName, settings.Password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(settings.ServiceEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { settings.Scope } // https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.report
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));


            return new AdMobService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "App"
            });
        }
```

But it return this error:

```
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): loading 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.1.2\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll' completed. 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware:Error: An unhandled exception has occurred: [{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "unauthorized"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
]

The service admob has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: [{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "unauthorized"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
] ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Google.Apis.Util.StandardResponse`1[System.Object]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureArrayContract(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input) in C:\Apiary\2020-06-01.14-07-07\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Core\Json\NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.cs:line 188
   at Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.<DeserializeError>d__37.MoveNext() in C:\Apiary\2020-06-01.14-07-07\Src\Support\Google.Apis\Services\BaseClientService.cs:line 333
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.<DeserializeError>d__37.MoveNext() in C:\Apiary\2020-06-01.14-07-07\Src\Support\Google.Apis\Services\BaseClientService.cs:line 341
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ParseResponse>d__31.MoveNext() in C:\Apiary\2020-06-01.14-07-07\Src\Support\Google.Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 249
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Is there a client for that where I could fetch a token, like this one

```
return new GooglePlayClient
            {
                TokenProvider = new TokenProvider(settings.ServiceEmail, settings.CertificateFileName, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher")
            };
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The [admob api](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/how-tos/authorizing) does not appear to support service account authentication.

> Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

Comment: Would the -1 care to comment as to the reason for the -1